# core data not being delete through protocol function

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, protocols, swift5

My code is trying to delete a elememnt from a set via button. When the button is pressed a runtime error occurs. The error states "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" at   let date = users[indx]. All I am doing is trying to delete a element from the core data set. I save the code in one class and iand display it through another. Link to git https://github.com/redrock34/core-Data-Delete.

```
    extension ViewController : datacollectionProfotocol {
func deleteData(indx: Int) {
    users.remove(at: indx)
    block.reloadData()

    let date = users[indx]
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Item")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"atBATS = %@", date as CVarArg)

    let result = try? context.fetch(request)
    let resultData = result as! [NSManagedObject]

    for object in resultData {
        context.delete(object)
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
        print(" saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Well you are doing `users.remove(at: indx)` right before so no wonder it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Really? Just do it in the opposite order, read before you remove

Comment: Should I delete users.remove(at: indx) from the function.

Comment: No that is not necessary

Comment: What do you mean by  Just do it in the opposite order, read before you remove

Comment: DO I delete anything from the function

Comment: You call `let date = users[indx]` before `users.remove(at: indx)` otherwise `indx` points at the wrong row

Comment: That works!. However its not deleting it forever. It deletes it and when the page reloads it reappears. I am trying to delete core data Item named atBATS which is a string.

Comment: Maybe so but now you asked about an error you got and that part is fixed now.